# Animation problem in LazyColumn when an object is displayed below it

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add an animation to a LazyColumn so that when an element appears underneath, an animation is made in which the element makes a fadeIn and scale effect.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimatedLazyColumn() {

    val items = remember { ('A'..'Z').map { it.toString() } }
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val lastVisibleItemIndex = listState.layoutInfo
            .visibleItemsInfo
            .lastOrNull()?.index ?: 1f

        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                horizontal = 16.dp,
                vertical = 30.dp
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->

                val animateAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
                    targetValue =
                    if (lastVisibleItemIndex == index) {
                        0f
                    } else {
                        1f
                    },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                    ),
                    label = ""
                )

                val animateScale by animateFloatAsState(
                    targetValue =
                    if (lastVisibleItemIndex == index) {
                        0.6f
                    } else {
                        1f
                    },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                    ),
                    label = ""
                )

                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .scale(animateScale)
                        .alpha(animateAlpha)
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                ) {
                    Text(item, color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works as I want, but because of the condition I have set, all the elements in the list are animated except the last one, which remains invisible

[image]

I would like the animation to go all the way to the last element and not remain hidden, what can I do? I don't know if this is the best way to do it, so I also accept advice.